# Ruby: the difference of "+=" and "<<"for String

Tags: ruby, string

```
a = %W(a b c).each {|a| a << "\n"}
a.each {|a| print a}
```

displays:
a
b
c

```
a = %W(a b c).each {|a| a += "\n"}
a.each {|a| print a}
```

dispays: abc

What causes this difference?

Comment: What research have you done so far? Have you tried printing out `a.inspect`?

Answer (score 3):

Note that `<<` is an *in-place* modifier, that is it alters what the string contains. `+=` is a combination *addition-assignment* operator that changes what the variable points to, but does not alter the original object.

Compare:

```
a = "a"
a.object_id
# => ...4680

a += "b"
a.object_id
# => ...3960
```

`a` is now pointing to a totally different object. When you do this inside your `each` loop you're not altering the original object stored in the array, you're altering the variable that only exists for the scope of the iteration of that loop.

Going one step further:

```
a << "c"
a.object_id
# => ...3960
```

It's still the same object. Strings, like a lot of *container*-type objects such as arrays and hashes, often have some methods which do in-place modifications and others that return copies. There's a huge difference between `String#sub` and `String#sub!`.